# Graph Algorithm (Modification on Dijkstra?) : Tech Interview

Tags: algorithm, graph

I only request **pseudo code** for this problem. I don't need actual code. Just merely practicing some graph algorithms.

Problem: Suppose we had a directed graph G with strictly positive edge weights between the vertices, a nonempty set A (special vertices) such that A is a subset of V where V are the vertices, a positive integer C, and a starting vertex S. Find the shortest path starting at S and containing **at least** C vertices in A (cycles OK). If no path exists, output -INF or +INF. Polynomial time algorithms only (in V,E, and C).

My attempt: If there atleast C vertices in A that I want to find, then maybe I could replicate the graph C times, where each replicated graph is like a layer. So when running Dijkstra, if I step into a special vertex, that vertex connects me to its counterpart in the next layer. If there are 10 vertices in the graph and I want to find when I step into the special vertices 3 times, then there will be 30 total vertices because each layer contains the identical looking 10 vertices.

I have issues translating this idea to any sort of (pseudo) code. Perhaps my idea isnt even valid, in that case, any help would be appreciated in proposals of a different solution.

Thank you.

Comment: if you are concerned about algorithm and not malfunctionning code, please post on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay! I will do that.

Comment: Depends on how large is C, do a 2D version of dijkstra instead of 1D, d[i][j] where it is shortest path from S to node i which passes exactly through j type A nodes

Comment: Algorithm questions are perfectly fine here; that's what the algorithm tag is for.